# Extended interface doesn't seem to implement parent members

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, interface, polymorphism

I have two interfaces

```
export interface IComponent{
    type: ComponentType;
    name: string;
    isEnabled:boolean;
}

export interface IAudioComponent extends IComponent {
    source: string;
    volume: number;
    loop: boolean;
    playbackRate: number;
}
```

But when I log a IAudioComponent in my VueComponent like this

```
  data() {
    return {
      _componentGroup: this.componentGroup as IComponentGroup,
      _focussedComponent: this.componentGroup.components[0] as IComponent,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    focussedComponentType() {
      console.log(this.$data._focussedComponent);
      return this.$data._focussedComponent.type;
    }
  },
```

I get the following output in the DOM

```
{__ob__: Observer}
loop: (...)
name: (...)
playbackRate: (...)
volume: (...)
__ob__: Observer {value: {…}, dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
get loop: ƒ reactiveGetter()
set loop: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
get name: ƒ reactiveGetter()
set name: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
get playbackRate: ƒ reactiveGetter()
set playbackRate: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
get volume: ƒ reactiveGetter()
set volume: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
__proto__: Object
```

Why doesn't it contain the type, name and isEnabled?

In the Typescript documentation they demonstrate that this should work

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#extending-interfaces

Comment: isEnabled:boolean, - you have a coma there, put semicolon as everywhere in your interfaces

Comment: Thanks, I changed it but I still have the same problem.

Comment: An interface does not add properties to an object. An interface's only purposes is to identify the shape of an object. If you did not add these properties yourself, they will not exist.

Comment: Right, then I am a bit confused why you can extend a interface with another interface and what the purpose is.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy are you sure about that? The typescript handbook says the following https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#extending-interfaces where they use square.color

Comment: I'm sure about that, they're assigning that property to the object, it doesn't exist before hand. You can try it yourself. Create an object and cast it to the interface, then console.log it, the property will not exist. Now, if you had a base class that you extended from, then of course, those properties would exist.

Comment: I see thanks I will use implement in that case

Comment: @MikeOttink: Interfaces just ensure that objects have certain properties, and some function might only need a more generic interface than another, so using the more generic one is preferable. You can extend an interface to make a more specific one, or you can combine many different capabilities into one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some very suspicious type assertions here:

```
  _componentGroup: this.componentGroup as IComponentGroup,
  _focussedComponent: this.componentGroup.components[0] as IComponent,
```

These just *claim* that the objects are of a specific type, they do not change the object. So unless these object actually are of that type they may not actually have any of the properties defined in the interface.